# The order of growth of $e^z-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be an entire function. If there exist a positive number $\rho$ and constants $A,B>0$ such that 
>   $$
> |f(z)|\leq Ae^{B|z|^{\rho}}\  \text{for all}\ z\in{\Bbb C}
> $$
>   then we say that $f$ has an order of growth $\leq\rho$. We define the order of growth of $f$ as 
>   $$
> \rho_f=\inf\rho
> $$
>   where the infimum is over all $\rho>0$ such that $f$ has an order of growth $\leq\rho$.

Here is my **question**:

> Using the definition above, how can I find the order of $f(z)=e^z-1$?

---

It's not hard to show that $$
|e^z-1|\leq e^{|z|}
$$
and thus $f$ has an order of growth $\leq 1$. I guess *the* order should be $1$. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$, and $A,B>0$, I need a $z\in{\Bbb C}$ such that 
$$
|e^z-1|> Ae^{B|z|^{1-\varepsilon}}.
$$
How can I go on?

Comment: What did you try? I would think focusing on real, positive $z$ would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it has order of growth $\leq 1$.

Now if it had order of growth $\leq \rho<1$, we would have
$$
|e^z-1|\leq Ae^{B|z|^\rho} \quad\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad |e^x-1|\leq Ae^{Bx^\rho} \quad\forall x>0.
$$
Hence
$$
e^x\leq |e^x-1|+1\leq(A+1)e^{Bx^\rho}\quad\Rightarrow\quad e^{x-Bx^\rho}\leq A+1$$
$$
\Rightarrow\quad x\left(1 -Bx^{\rho-1}\right)= x-Bx^\rho\leq\log(A+1)\quad\forall x>0.
$$
Now the lhs clearly tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$. Contradiction.

Comment: How do you get $|e^x-1|+1\leq (A+1)e^{Bx^\rho}$? for all $x>0$?

Comment: @Jack $|e^x-1|+1\leq Ae^{Bx^\rho}+1\leq Ae^{Bx^\rho}+e^{Bx^\rho}=(A+1)e^{Bx^\rho}$ because $e^{Bx^\rho}\geq 1$ as the argument is positive.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\rho<1$, and $A,B>0$, one needs a $z\in{\Bbb C}$ such that 
$$
|e^z-1|> Ae^{B|z|^{\rho}}.
$$

This is actually asking if the inequality has a solution. If we focus on $z=x>0$, then the inequality is 
$$
 e^x-1> Ae^{Bx^{\rho}}
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
e^{x-Bx^\rho}-e^{-Bx^\rho}>A\tag{*}
$$
But
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}(e^{x-Bx^\rho}-e^{-Bx^\rho})=\lim_{x\to+\infty}
(e^{x^\rho(x^{1-\rho}-B)}-e^{-Bx^\rho})=+\infty.
$$
Thus ($*$) must have a solution.